# ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Tags: java

Estoy intentando guardar como una imagen el contenido de todo un LinearLayout (con su background de fondo) que contiene varios  editText, En mi Activity tengo mi codigo asi, que me sale error cuando le doy click en el boton guardar.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout backgroundLayout;
    private EditText editText1;
    private EditText editText2;
    private Button saveButton;
    private int imageCounter = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        backgroundLayout = findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
        editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Combina el fondo y el texto en un solo Bitmap
                Bitmap combinedBitmap = createCombinedBitmap();

                // Guarda la imagen con un nombre único
                saveImageToFile(combinedBitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    private Bitmap createCombinedBitmap() {
        Bitmap backgroundBitmap = loadBackgroundBitmap();
        String text1 = editText1.getText().toString();
        String text2 = editText2.getText().toString();

        // Combina el fondo y el texto en un solo Bitmap
        Bitmap combinedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                backgroundBitmap.getWidth(),
                backgroundBitmap.getHeight(),
                backgroundBitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(combinedBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        // Agrega el texto a la imagen

        return combinedBitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap loadBackgroundBitmap() {
       return null;
    }

    private void saveImageToFile(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        File directory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);

        // Crea un nombre de archivo único basado en el contador
        String fileName = "imagen_" + imageCounter + ".png";
        File file = new File(directory, fileName);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            // Notifica al usuario que la imagen se ha guardado con éxito
            Toast.makeText(this, "Imagen guardada en " + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Incrementa el contador
            imageCounter++;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al guardar la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Maneja cualquier error que pueda ocurrir al guardar la imagen
        }
    }
}

Intento Guardar la imagen y me salen estos errores:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: appskd.bateria.appguardarimagen, PID: 28463
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
        at appskd.bateria.appguardarimagen.MainActivity.createCombinedBitmap(MainActivity.java:53)
        at appskd.bateria.appguardarimagen.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:16)
        at appskd.bateria.appguardarimagen.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Me sale este error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Comment: You are returning 'null' on your loadBackgroundBitmap() method. Also for better answer try asking question in English next time.

Comment: Por favor escribe en ingles o usa [es.so]

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly states that you are returning a `null` on

```
> private Bitmap loadBackgroundBitmap() {
>        return null;
>     }
```

and you are trying to access the `getWidth()` on your null object in your `createCombinedBitmap()` method.

you can fix it by updating your `loadBackgroundBitmap()`
for example:

```
private Bitmap loadBackgroundBitmap() {
// do not return as null. load your background here.
}
```

Also handle your potential null cases. for example:

```
  Bitmap backgroundBitmap = loadBackgroundBitmap();
    if (backgroundBitmap == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This Background Bitmap is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Me funciono la segunda opcion, pero al ejecutar me saca este error java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB,  en el private Bitmap loadBackgroundBitmap